# Select Record from database randomly based on time

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2005

I want to select records from database randomly based on time.

example
I have table with name Table1 having thousand of records, now every hour i want to display around 100 questions hourly but for every hour they should be random. How can achieve it.

I dont want to create a separate table which 100 of columns and store record Id of master table , instead i want to use some logic where i will pass date and time and i can get 100 questions for that hours.

I am using sqlserver 2005.

I will be very thankfull, if any one can help me in solving this problem.

Can i do it following way
create new table with id,datetime, string rowno
and save the id seperated by comma?

do you think there can be any issue in this??

Comment: Hi,

Can i do it following way
create new table with id,datetime, string rowno
and save the id seperated by comma?

do you think there can be any issue in this??

Answer (score 0):

The way I would attempt this would be:

```
SELECT TOP 100 [Column_Name]
FROM ...
WHERE [Column_Name] >= DATEADD(hour,-1,GETDATE());
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

This would get 100 records that were created within the last hour and they will be gathered randomly.

Comment: I don't think he wanted rows that were created in the last hour, but that the list of random rows is static for one hour.

Comment: Well if its possible for you, you can code a console application which runs the query every hour and just store the results in the back-end code and just display the information where you want it through the back-end storage. This would assure that your results stay static for whatever time you want. Not really sure how or where you're displaying your information but this has worked for me in the past in previous projects.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with a simple query. Plan on something that will become a stored procedure.

The pseudo-random number generator in SQL-SERVER generator uses a seed (tiny-int,int, small-int) and randomly generates a floating point number between 0 and 1. Hopefully, you have some kind of numeric key for your records.
You'll need to:

(1) Set up a WHILE loop to do this. Make sure you also use a reasonable counter variable. Increment it and check it with every iteration of the loop because a runaway loop is no fun.

(2) Use RAND() to generate the floating point number.You can use something from the date and time to use as a seed. It MUST change every time because calling RAND(seed) again with the same seed gives you the same number.
The following is from SQL-SERVER 2005 books online:

```
    SELECT RAND( (DATEPART(mm, GETDATE()) * 100000 )
        + (DATEPART(ss, GETDATE()) * 1000 )
        + DATEPART(ms, GETDATE()) )
```

(You can read up on this: look for RAND() in the Transact-SQL reference. There is a link there that will tell you all about this.

(2) Multiply that generated decimal number by some power of ten to get an integer.

(3) Store these numbers someplace, maybe in a table object or a temp table

(4) Check the new number against the stored table to make sure it's not a dup (unlikely but you never know). For that reason, as well as insurance against a runaway loop, use a counter limit greater than 100.If you do have a dup, generate a new number until you don't get one (another while loop) Don't put any numbers in that second temp table until you're sure they are not dupes.

(5) When the number of records in your temp table gets to 100, you should be done. You can just tract this in a variable, but you might want to check that variable against the actual number in the end.

(6) If you want to make sure this numbers are unique over time;i.e. don't ever get the same record twice, just insert all the numbers from your temp table into one you keep. You can repopulate the temp table from that permanent one before you begin. You could also clear out that table after some amount of time (a month, a year, whatever).

(7) When you're sure this works, convert it into a stored proc. You can probably run this as a job every day.

Hope this works. When you get that stored proc done, why not post it (with comments) as an answer so everyone can see how to do it. Also, make sure you can access a copy of MS-SqlServer Books on Line; The Transact-SQL reference is invaluable.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE CurrentQuestions
(
    QuestionId int
)
```

Then every hour run a procedure such as the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PopulateCurrentQuestions
AS
BEGIN
    DELETE CurrentQuestions

    INSERT INTO 
        CurrentQuestions
    SELECT TOP 100
        Questions.ID
    FROM
        Questions
    WHERE
        ID % DATEPART(hh, GETDATE()) = 0
    ORDER BY
        NEWID()
END
```

Then the query to display those questions becomes:

```
SELECT
    Questions.Title,
    Questions.Content,
    Questions.WhateverElse
FROM
    Questions
    INNER JOIN CurrentQuestions ON Questions.ID = CurrentQuestions.QuestionID
```

You can then run that procedure however often you want. Also you could change the `ID % DATEPART(hh, GETDATE()) = 0`to some other criteria to select the pseudo random questions.

Comment: Hi Tobsey, In your logic there are 2 problems, first you are not picking random records, 2nd you are deleting them, so in case i want to reterieve them back, how i will do it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to do this. If you don’t already have identity column for the table that holds questions just go ahead and add one.

```
select top 100 *
from Questions Q
where Q.QuestionID % 24 = DATEPART(hour, (CONVERT(datetime, GETDATE())))
order by NEWID()
```

This will assign integer ID for each of the questions. Idea is to use modulus based on current hour. So if it’s 1.30 AM date part will return 1 so all questions that have IDs like (1,25,49,…) will be returned.  At the end you just use order by to randomize them.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with following steps

I created new table with id,datetime, string rowno.
In rowno, I have selected random number id of 100 rows and save it in COMMA seperated form.

It is working properly.

In most of the above proposed soln, i think something is missing, it might be possible that i was not able to ask it properly.

Thanks for all your suggestions.